# cakephp: undefined variable error when passing variable from controller to view

Tags: cakephp, variables, view, controller

When I click submit in signup page, I'm getting `"Notice (8): Undefined variable: id [APP\views\merry_parents\report_card.ctp".`

I'm just trying to pass `$this->data['MerryParent']['id']` from `merry_parents_controller` to the report_card view using `$this->set($id,$this->data['MerryParent']['id']);`

Can someone tell me on what i'm doing wrong? thanks in advance.

following is my code:

```
//report_card.ctp

 <?php
     echo 'HALLO';
     echo $id;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$this->set('id', $this->data['MerryParent']['id']);
```

The first argument is the desired name *as a string*, not as a variable.